# Angular + rxjs : pattern for collection filtering where filter and collection are streams

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there a better way to write this. I want to load some data , subscribe to a behavior subject which is loaded in a a dropdown, on every change i want to filter the data. It works but not sure this is the best way of writing this with nesting the BehaviorSubject or should I subscribe in the completed event of the forkJoin which is loading data from http

```
ngOnInit() {

//load all the data

let array1: Observable<any[]> = this.service1.getAll();

let array2: Observable<any[]> = this.service2.getAll();    

let observableBatch = [array1, array2];


Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe(data => {

  this.items1 = data[0] as Array<any>;

  this.items2 = data[1] as Array<any>   


  //subscribe to BehaviorSubject Observable, filter on every change        
  this.someService.selectedItem$.subscribe((item: any) => {

    if (item) {         

      this.filterItemsByItemId(item.itemId);
    }

   }, (error:any)=>{

  //error

});     


}, (error: any) => {

  //error


});
```

}

Comment: why subscribe inside a subscribe? thats weird

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question? I need to load a bunch of arrays and once loaded filter them by subscribing to a behavior subject that is loaded one the app loads. Can you show me a better way instead of asking me the question

Comment: WHY are you using a nested subscribe? Because I don't see you use `item1` or `items2` inside you second subscribe

Comment: items1 and items2 are filtered according to the behavior subject value which initially emits a value but my change so I need to load the arrays before filtering them. this.filterItemsByItemId(item.itemId);  Inside that method is this.items1.filter

Comment: I'm just wondering maybe I should move to the completed event to subscribe instead of nesting, it's not  weird btw, this isn't a simple heros app, this app has millions of lines of code and complex components...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have a nested subscribe is really weird.
Normally I use the following approach (assuming that you load all the data only once):

```
@Component({
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class FooComponent {
  dataOne$: Observable<any[]>; // depending on if you use the unfiltered collections or not this members can be removed
  dataTwo$: Observable<any[]>;

  selected$: Observable<any>;    
  filteredOne$: Observable<any[]>;
  filteredTwo$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(){
   this.dataOne$ = this.service1.getAll()
     .share(); // avoid multiple requests for this data
   this.dataTwo$ = this.service2.getAll()
     .share(); // avoid multiple requests for this data

   this.selected$ = this.someService.selected$; // this should be an exposed observable, not the Subject itself

   filteredOne$ = this.selected$
    .withLatestFrom(this.dataOne$,(selected,elements)=>({selected,elements}))
    .map(data => elements.filter(element => //add filter logic using data.selected));
   filteredTwo$ = this.selected$
    .withLatestFrom(this.dataTwo$,(selected,elements)=>({selected,elements})
    .map(data => elements.filter(element => // add filter logic using data.selected));    
  }
}
```

}

What I archive with this:

- Change detection on push
- Mostly exclusive use of the `async` pipe to extract data from observables

With this approach you use the `selected$` stream in the template to render the current value, and the `filtered$` streams to render the filtered elements of the corresponding collections.

In the case that the data collections can emit new values, then I normally use the **static** [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) operator instead of the [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html). The difference between both of them is explained [here](http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/03/27/the-difference-between-rxjs-combinelatest-and-withlatestfrom/).

An trust me on this one: wherever you call subscribe, your code can be refactored to (ab)use the `async` pipe :D

Comment: that looks way better, I don't know withLatestFrom, I'm going to go look that up right now. yes the filter is an exposed observable not the subscription. It's a dropdown in the app header so when it changes it emit/pushes the new value and the components subscibed will filter the data. Thanks so much

Comment: in that case the push of a new value in the stream should trigger the refilter of the collections :)

Comment: yeah, I haven't ran into this type of pattern yet, I'm constantly learning something new with rxjs, thank you very much.

Comment: glad it helped, we all started like that ;)

Comment: BTW, dont take this as an absolute truth. There might be better ways to handle the same. Rx is a world of possibilities

Comment: yeah, I'm actually going to leave what I have for now until I understand more of that operator but instead of nesting going to move to the completed  event. I have a component that loads up all the items then depending what is selected in the behavior subject observable that sits inside the app header so fires on every change need the data table to filter. It works how I have it even though may look a bit weird but maybe calling a function in completed will look better until I can understand more of what you posted.

Comment: I don't know share either, I was using forkjoin to load multiple arrays at same time inside the component and filter by initial value of the behavior subject then filter on every change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem on your data loading, what bothers me is the behaviorSubject. Why would you do that, when you have input bindings in Angular ?

I guess your dropdown is a `<select>`. This gives

```html
<select #myDropdown (change)="changeValue(myDropdown.value)">
  <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
```

In your component :

```js
changeValue(value) {
  // Let's say you request an endpoint
  this.myService.myMethod(value).subscribe(data => /* do your thing here */);

  // Want to filter your data ? No problem 
  this.items1 = this.items1.filter(item => item['your property here'] === value);
  this.items2 = this.items2.filter(item => item['your property here'] === value);
}
```

This seems a lot easier and shorter, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah I know, it's a dropdown outside of the component that changes a lot in the app so I need to subscribe to it. it sits in the topbar and when changing the menu changes, the users filters, the roles filter so it's needs to be that type.

Comment: Still don't see the need of a BehaviorSubject, I have a similar application and I don't use it. But anyways, if you want to use it, I don't see any problem in your code, even though it's just an exemple !

Comment: because it's a routed component so there's no way for me to input a component inside the top bar to a component that is inside another component in another module. It's a complex app so not just simple componets on the page, I am using input binding to bind the selectedItem to other components

Comment: And an application service couldn't do the trick ? I always have a `SessionService` where I store all of my user data/choices, such as themes, accounts, etc. And I don't see the binding, so that might explain the confusion !

Comment: yeah that's what I'm doing but using behavior subjects so value is pushed to the components and they react accordingly.

Comment: but anyways besides the architecture, I'm just wondering if I should subscribe in the completed event instead of nesting?

Comment: Well, if it's only a depth 2 nest, that's not a callback hell. But what you could do is create a subscription, and assign it to your second subscription like so `this.mySubscription = this.someService.selectedItem$.subscribe(...)`, or create a function out of the first subscribe. I think the function outside would be muche clearer than nesting your subscriptions !

Comment: I have it nested because the behavior subject will initially emit a value and fires on every change, it's a dropdown in the header of the app so I need the arrays filled first before filtering, I'm guessing I should just call a function in the completed event which does the subscription instead of nesting.